# Java servelet to redirect images request to aem dam

Tags: tomcat, servlets, aem

I need help with some servlet. I have two projects, one that uses tomcat and other that uses AEM(Adobe Experience Manager). In this second that uses AEM, I have all the assets(images...) and I wanna develop a servlet to redirect all images request from the first project to DAM of the second project. I've searching a lot about this, but no solid solution.
Can you guys help me? I already developed a servlet filter, but it's not working.

I'm trying to use this code, but I need it listening all the time, and then when a image is requested, it redirect to AEM local DAM.
[Click here](https://github.com/HeroDigital/renditions-servlet)

Comment: A filter would be a great way to go.  Can you post what you have and what isn't working?

Comment: Maybe you don't need to write custom code. This sounds like a job for an HTTP server set up as a cache/proxy or a CDN.